# How to tune valid indents with class and “make” method of FilamentPHP code?

Tags: phpstorm

Working with Laravel 10 / FilamentPHP 3 app in PhpStorm 2023.2.2. When I run "Reformat Code" command I want to have both class and `make` method at the same line, but with valid indents on next lines, not like I have now:

```php
return $form
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\Card::make()
                             ->schema([
                                 TextInput::make('id')->lazy()->disabled()->dehydrated(false)
```

But like this:

```php
return $form
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\Card::make()
            ->schema([
                 TextInput::make('id')->lazy()->disabled()->dehydrated(false)
```

Something like I see in docs :
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/creating-records#customizing-the-save-notification

Are there some options for this?

Comment: What do you have for `Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls | Align when multiline` -- that's the best option right now that comes into my mind from such a small & limited code fragment.

Comment: If it's not the one then: 1) share this file (Google Drive or alike) -- you can remove some private stuff of you have, but must have enough code to have this issue reproducible; 2) export your Code Style as XML file and share with that file (so it can be imported locally and played around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PhpStorm:
`Ctrl+Alt+S -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP`
Choose Schema. Choose what you need to change (I assume it's `Tabs and Indents` and `Wrapping and Braces`)

Comment: I found these 2 tabs, but not sure which options have I to cxhange ?